# Compare different speeds of parametrizations in same animation box

Tags: plotting, animation

I recently taught my calculus III students about arclength parametrizations, and I wanted to show them the different parametrizations in action, but in Mathematica, there seems to be a default speed for Animate.  I tried to remedy this (code below) by having both parametrizations in a single Animate application.  The result was that one parametrization ran through the desired range, but the other one was much shorter.

My desire is to run the animations next to each other, with each of them running through the whole curve, but doing at it their respective speeds.

```
Animate[ 
 GraphicsRow[
  {ParametricPlot3D[
 {10*Cos[t], 10*Sin[t], 9*t},{t, -3*Pi, a},PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, {-5, 315}}],
   ParametricPlot3D[{10*Cos[t/Sqrt[181]], 10*Sin[t/Sqrt[181]],t/Sqrt[181]},
    {t, -3*Pi, a},
      PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, {-5, 315}}]}],
    {a, 2*Pi, 15*Pi}]
```

Comment: The second parameterization only goes through about half a revolution over the range `t={-3 pi,15 pi}`. You'll have to clarify the behavior you want. If you want the same speed, but with the first animation stopping when it reaches the end set the first t range to `{t,-3*pi,Min[a,15*pi]}` and then let `a` go over the range {a,2*pi,15*pi*Sqrt[181]}

Comment: When I change the range so that the second parametrization carves out the whole curve, the first one goes so fast that it essentially just appears immediately.

To try to be clearer, I like the speeds that the current version go, but I want to be able to allow the second parametrization to traverse the whole curve without changing the speed of it (or the first one).

Comment: You're going to have to change the speed of one of the curves. The second curve is about 100 times slower relative to t. If you change the second t range to `{t, -3*Pi, a*315/(15*\[Pi])*Sqrt[181]}` they will finish at the same time and the speed looks good. You can take smaller steps so that the speed of curve 1 doesn't change without changing the speed of 2, but then you'll have to wait 100x longer for curve 2 to finish up.